# Radio&Checkbox buttons Contact form 7 not clickable

Tags: forms, plugin-contact-form-7

This is the code.In documentation

[checkbox* your-country use_label_element "China" "India" "San Marino"]

[radio your-sports label_first default:2 "Football" "Tennis" "Pole-vault"]

But the radio and checkboxes are not clickable in my code?What am I missing here?

```
<div class="custom-control custom-radio">
[radio customRadio id:customRadio1 class:custom-control-input]
<label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio1">Something</label>
</div>
<div class="custom-control custom-radio">
[radio customRadio id:customRadio2 class:custom-control-input]
<label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio2">Something</label>
</div>

<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
   [checkbox checkbox1 id:customCheck1 class:custom-control-input]
   <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1">Something</label>
 </div>
 <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
  [checkbox checkbox2 id:customCheck2 class:custom-control-input]
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck2">Something</label>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use below html and shortcode in the contact form .you missed the checkbox and radio button values

```
<div class="custom-control custom-radio">
    [radio customRadio id:customRadio1 class:custom-control-input "value4"]
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio1">Something</label>
</div>

<div class="custom-control custom-radio">
    [radio customRadio id:customRadio2 class:custom-control-input "value5"]
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio2">Something</label>
</div>

<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    [checkbox checkbox1 id:customCheck1 class:custom-control-input "Value1"]
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1">Something</label>
</div>

<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    [checkbox checkbox2 id:customCheck2 class:custom-control-input "value2"]
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck2">Something</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Trilok, you were a great help thnx. But after I use your code this is after inspect element shows up                                                                                                 
<div class=wpcf7-form-control-wrap customRadio>
<span class="class="wpcf7-list-item first last">
<input type="radio" name="customRadio" value="value1" checked="checked">
<span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">value1</span>
::before
"value1"
::after
</span>
</span>
</span>
</span>
<label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio1">Example</label>
::before
"Example"
</label>
</div>

Comment: so what's problem you facing

Comment: Trilok fixed it instead of using CF7 tags used HTML tags and worked.Thnx for everything.